# Use underscore to count occurrences and fill missing values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Suppose I have series of numbers between 1 and 10. I want to know the frequency of occurrence for each number. I could do this:

```
var a = [4,5,6,7,8,9,4,6,8,9,3,5,7,8,4,5,8,4,7];
var b = _.countBy(a, _.identity);
```

But `console.log(b)` yields:

```
Object {
 //1=0,  this is missing
 //2=0,  this is missing
   3=1,
   4=4,
   5=3,
   6=2,
   7=3,
   8=4,
   9=2,
//10=0   this is missing
}
```

So the `1`, `2` and `10` categories are missing.

*Using underscore*, how can I force them to be included, with zero as their values?

Comment: If you just have to use underscore and make this complicated, something like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/a632M/20/

Comment: @adeneo Yeah want to know how using underscore, not `Array` :) I'm sure it's possible, I'm just new to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var a = [4,5,6,7,8,9,4,6,8,9,3,5,7,8,4,5,8,4,7],
    obj = {};
_.each(_.range(1, 11), function(item) {
        obj[item] = 0
})
_.each(a, function(item) {
    ++obj[item]; 
});
```

obj will be:

```
{
    "1": 0,
    "2": 0,
    "3": 1,
    "4": 4,
    "5": 3,
    "6": 2,
    "7": 3,
    "8": 4,
    "9": 2,
    "10": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With plain javascript you can do

```js
var array = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 6, 8, 9, 3, 5, 7, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 7];

var counts = {};

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  counts[i] = 0;
}

array.forEach(function(number) {
  counts[number]++;
});

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: Yes in plain js I can do it, but I want to know how in underscore.